# per process configurable core dump directory

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, coredump

Is there a way to configure the directory where core dump files are placed for a specific process?

I have a daemon process written in C++ for which I would like to configure the core dump directory. Optionally the filename pattern should be configurable, too.

I know about `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, however this would change the pattern and directory structure *globally*.

Apache has the directive `CoreDumpDirectory` - so it seems to be possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you cannot set it per process. The core file gets dumped either to the current working directory of the process, or the directory set in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern if the pattern includes a directory.

CoreDumpDirectory in apache is a hack, apache registers signal handlers for all signals that cause a core dump , and changes the current directory in its signal handler.

```
/* handle all varieties of core dumping signals */
static void sig_coredump(int sig)
{
    apr_filepath_set(ap_coredump_dir, pconf);
    apr_signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
#if AP_ENABLE_EXCEPTION_HOOK
    run_fatal_exception_hook(sig);
#endif
    /* linuxthreads issue calling getpid() here:
     *   This comparison won't match if the crashing thread is
     *   some module's thread that runs in the parent process.
     *   The fallout, which is limited to linuxthreads:
     *   The special log message won't be written when such a
     *   thread in the parent causes the parent to crash.
     */
    if (getpid() == parent_pid) {
        ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_NOTICE,
                     0, ap_server_conf,
                     "seg fault or similar nasty error detected "
                     "in the parent process");
        /* XXX we can probably add some rudimentary cleanup code here,
         * like getting rid of the pid file.  If any additional bad stuff
         * happens, we are protected from recursive errors taking down the
         * system since this function is no longer the signal handler   GLA
         */
    }
    kill(getpid(), sig);
    /* At this point we've got sig blocked, because we're still inside
     * the signal handler.  When we leave the signal handler it will
     * be unblocked, and we'll take the signal... and coredump or whatever
     * is appropriate for this particular Unix.  In addition the parent
     * will see the real signal we received -- whereas if we called
     * abort() here, the parent would only see SIGABRT.
     */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make it using the "|command" mechanism of the core_pattern file. The executed command can create the directories and files as needed. The command can be passed the following specifiers in the parameters (cf. [man 5 core](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)):

> **%%** a single % character
> **%c** core file size soft resource limit of crashing process
> **%d** dump mode—same as value returned by prctl(2) PR_GET_DUMPABLE
> **%e** executable filename (without path prefix)
> **%E** pathname of executable, with slashes ('/') replaced by exclamation marks ('!')
> **%g** (numeric) real GID of dumped process
> **%h** hostname (same as nodename returned by uname(2))
> **%i** TID of thread that triggered core dump, as seen in the PID namespace in which the thread resides
> **%I** TID of thread that triggered core dump, as seen in the initial PID namespace
> **%p** PID of dumped process, as seen in the PID namespace in which the process resides
> **%P** PID of dumped process, as seen in the initial PID namespace
> **%s** number of signal causing dump
> **%t** time of dump, expressed as seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)
> **%u** (numeric) real UID of dumped process

For example, it is possible to create a script (e.g. named crash.sh) as follow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# $1: process number on host side (%P)
# $2: program's name (%e)

OUTDIR=/tmp/core/$2
OUTFILE="core_$1"

# Create a sub-directory in /tmp
mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"

# Redirect stdin in a per-process file:
cat > "$OUTDIR"/"$OUTFILE"

exit 0
```

In the shell:

```
$ chmod +x crash.sh
$ mv crash.sh /tmp  # Put the script in some place
$ sudo su
# echo '|/tmp/crash.sh %P %e' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/tmp/crash.sh %P %e
# exit
$
```

Create an example program which crashes (e.g. fail.c):

```
int main(void)
{
  char *ptr = (char *)0;

  *ptr = 'q';

  return 0;

}
```

Compile the program (make several executables) and adjust the core file size in the current shell:

```
$ gcc fail.c -o fail1
$ gcc fail.c -o fail2
$ ulimit -c
0
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ulimit -c
unlimited
```

Run the failing programs several times to have multiple processes ids:

```
$ ./fail1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./fail2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./fail1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ./fail2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Look at /tmp where the core_pattern redirects the core dumps:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/core
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 nov.    3 15:57 fail1
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 nov.    3 15:57 fail2
$ ls -l /tmp/core/fail1/
total 480
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 245760 nov.    3 15:57 core_10606
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 245760 nov.    3 15:57 core_10614
$ ls -l /tmp/core/fail2 
total 480
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 245760 nov.    3 15:57 core_10610
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 245760 nov.    3 15:57 core_10618
```